# Redirecting webpage to another webpage

Tags: redirect, header, timed

Just wanna ask if its possible to have like "header(location: mysite.com)", but it is TIMED. let's say for five seconds then refresh, but after refresh, it'll go to another site (like http://mysecondsite.com).

It is like, "click here" --> site.php (which contain header(location: mysite.com), BUT TIMED ) --> after five seconds it'll automatically go to like mysecondsite.com

Comment: This general question has already been addressed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402009/setting-php-timer-based-functions. Note however, that doing this with PHP is not advised, and you would be better served with a JavaScript solution.

Comment: I would have proposed an HTML solution, like a META refresh. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125661/javascript-page-reload-or-meta-tag-refresh-method if you cannot decide between Javascript & a meta refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function which will redirect to the second page within a javascript setTimeout() function.

Something like this:

```
<button onClick="setTimeout(function() {
window.location.href = 'http://mysecondsite.com';
}, 5000);"> 
Pause Then Go
</button>
```

Here's a quick tut on the javascript: [Javascript setTimeout() and setInterval()](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: So I'll write the above script inside "mysite.php"?

Comment: Yea. I don't know how exactly you will be implementing this.. but putting the above in an onClick() property would be a way to do it.

Comment: I made a few changes above which shows an example of how to write it into your HTML.

Comment: If you try putting it within your php like @user3727485 mentioned, then you will have it redirect after the page is loaded for a few seconds. I believe what you are wanting is the page to be redirected _after input from the user_. You will need to do it using something the user can interact with such as a button or link element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pause for certain time before refresh/redirecting ? if so, your answer here :

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://yoursite.com/');
```

Comment: yes, I've tried this one, but it doesn't go the second site.

Comment: Is any output before the header statement executed ?